# How can I push down actions to nla strips with python?

Tags: python, animation

I'm trying to write a script that push down all actions in NLA-Editor. No matter how many actions exist, it should work.

This is the code I currently have:

```
bpy.context.area.type = "NLA_EDITOR"
bpy.ops.nla.action_pushdown(channel_index = 1)
```

My problem is that I don't know what channel_index each action has. How can I get this index? Or is there a way to iterate through all actions in in the nla editor?

Comment: Agree with your answer, using API methods rather than `bpy.ops`.  In answer to your question re channel index, could use `nla_tracks.find(trackname)`  which returns either channel, or -1 if not found.

Comment: thank you for your answer!
Now I'm not gonna try it, but I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 7):

I have the answer:

I don't Need to go to nla-editor, I just add a new track and a new Strip with the Action, which I get from my object.

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.object:
    if obj.animation_data is not None:
        action = obj.animation_data.action
        if action is not None:
            track = obj.animation_data.nla_tracks.new()
            track.strips.new(action.name, action.frame_range[0], action)
            obj.animation_data.action = None
```