# python navigation to NLA sub-track of an object

Tags: python, shape-keys, nla-editor

I need to fix up animation on a character mesh every time I resync a linked armature, because the related mesh shape_keys animation gets deleted.  Manually I have to navigate to the mesh object, expand, find a track(?) called "Key.005", *Add* a Track and then find and assign my an action named "Key.005Action" to this NlaTrack (yes, really!).

I want to script around this ... predicament.

How do I script to find the key below the desired mesh name, select and add a track here?

[image]

Once I find and select the "Key.005" *item/row* I could then:

```
bpy.ops.nla.tracks_add(above_selected=False)
bpy.ops.nla.actionclip_add(action='Key.005Action')
```

Unfortunately [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98142/111042) nor [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88646/111042) doesn't get me there as nla_tracks for the main object are empty, as will be for the Key.005 sub-whatever.

I include a simple file with a cube with shape keys.  How do I assign the KeyAction to "Key.001" with a python script?  (but remember that the action on "Key" of "Cube" was deleted upon a resync!)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't quite follow, but the tracks for a shapekey are at `obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data.nla_tracks`.

Comment: @scurest -- ```obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data.nla_tracks[:]``` returns ```[]``` if there is no existing NlaTrack there, as happens when I resync the armature.  So I need to find the "Key.005" *row* somehow, to then ```tracks_add()```.

Comment: You can create a new track/strip directly without using an op, see eg [this A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88646/88681).

Comment: @scurest -- I need to find the node "Key.005" that lives *inside* some hierarchy.  You are not helping me find this node to operate on.  I had already visited that link: ```obj.animation_data.nla_tracks.new()``` will put a new track in the *wrong* place, and assigning the Key.005Action there will throw an error. ```Could not add action 'Key.005Action' as it cannot be used relative to ID-blocks of type 'OBGenesis8Male.Shape.001'```

Comment: I already said the tracks are `obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data.nla_tracks` so you would do `obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data.nla_tracks.new()`.

Comment: @scurest -- I now realize ... I need to know how to add an nla track to my meshes ```ob.data.shape_keys``` (bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.005'])! I added to my question and supplied a blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy
action = bpy.data.actions["KeyAction"]
ob = bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]
track = ob.data.shape_keys.animation_data.nla_tracks.new()
track.strips.new(action.name, 1, action)
```

Comment: Gracias, mon ami; to mix languages!